# namespace в dll

Tags: c++, dll

Пишу `dll` на `C++`. Можно ли помещать в ней функцию в `namespace`? Если да, то какой в этом профит, кроме решения проблемы неуникальности имен и как вызывать такую функцию из `exe`, если пользоваться `GetProcessAddress`? Если нет, то почему нельзя `namespace`-ом отделять такие блоки в `dll`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно помещать. Да, для решения вопроса с неуникальностью имен. Для того namepace и предназначены, независимо от того, в DLL они использованы или нет.

Если вы хотите пользоваться именно `GetProcAddress` (а не `dllimport`), то смотрите глазами после компиляции DLL, под каким именем и индексом экспортировалась функция.

Есть возможность "облагородить" экспортируемые имена через опции линкера, в т.ч. прямо в коде через

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/EXPORT:MyName=_MangledName@@#123#@@")
```

но для этого все равно надо знать "зашифрованное" имя. Ну и, понятное дело, в таком случае вопрос уникальности экспортируемых имен снова становится вашей ответственностью.